# How to convert first column of dataframe in to its headers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe df:

```
    0
0   a
1   b
2   c
3   d
4   e
```

O/P should be:

```
   a  b  c  d  e
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

I want column containing(a, b,c,d,e) as header of my dataframe.

Could anyone help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dataframe is pandas and its name is df. Try solving it with pandas:

Firstly convert initial df content to a list, afterwards create a new dataframe defining its columns with the list.

```
import pandas as pd

list = df[0].tolist()    #df[0] is getting the content of first column
dfSolved = pd.DataFrame([], columns = list)
```

Comment: You should also take the https://stackoverflow.com/tour for a better understanding of this platform. @shitalgawande

Answer (score 1):

You may provide more details like the index and values of the expected output, the operation you wanna do, etc, so that we could give a specific solution to your case

Here is the solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import numpy as np

data_string = """    columns_name
0   a
1   b
2   c
3   d
4   e
"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data_string), sep='\s+')

# Solution
df_result = pd.DataFrame(data=[[np.nan]*5],
                         columns=df['columns_name'].tolist())
```